# in Samsung device (SM-J200F-sdk 22) app crashes when calling intent for ACTION_VIEW (geo / map) But Works on many other devices! any solution?

Tags: android, android-intent, crash, geo

the error comes from this lines of code :

`Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("geo:" + mission.Customer.Lat + "," + mission.Customer.Lng)); 
startActivity(intent);`

this is the error :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no app available to handle `geo:` URIs. Install one such as Google Maps to the device.
2. In your app, catch `ActivityNotFoundException` when starting external activities. Add some kind of graceful degradation such as launch a web URL for the same coordinates or display an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that google map application enabled in this device sometimes the application disabled from device settings and cause this problem

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this crash when starting an activity with implicit intent. You should use the below code to verify whether there is a package with an activity that matches the give criteria. more [here](https://github.com/john-lq/android-example-kotlin/blob/implicit-intent-for-dialing-a-phone-number/ImplicitIntentForDialing/src/main/java/com/lqjohn/implicitintentfordialing/MainActivity.kt) or [here](https://youtu.be/6jBrcviclLE)

Using Kotlin:

```
if(intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null){
      startActivity(intent)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The exception can be printed:

```
try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The exception could be:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException(Calling startActivity() from
outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
Is this really what you want?)
```

In that case, you should add:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: The specific exception shown in the question is not the one in your answer.